# how to run the same iteration of a loop for a specific condition

Tags: python, for-loop, valueerror

input should accept any floating point values for n and terminate if ‘q’ is entered as the first value. If ‘q’ is entered as the second, third, fourth or fifth value, the program should produce a plot with only those values. For all other input, the program should print a message
indicating that there was an issue and ask the user to enter a value for n again. The program should NOT terminate on bad input. Run your program for

```
n=5
n_list=[]
for i in range(n):
    x=input('enter exponent n(q to quit) >')
    if i!=0 and x=='q':
        return n_list 
    elif  i==0 and x=='q':
        return('')
    try:
        float(x)
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a number!!!")
    n_list.append(float(x) )
```

when the exception of valueerror occurs is there a way where i can return back to the begging of the loop for the same iteratiom.

Answer (score 0):

After you've handled your `ValueError` from trying to convert to `float`, you do the exact same thing that might have caused the error, but this time without handling it.

Just do the append in the `try`.

```
n = 5
n_list = []
for i in range(n):
    x = input('enter exponent n(q to quit) >')
    if i != 0 and x == 'q':
        return n_list 
    elif i == 0 and x == 'q':
        return ''
    try:
        n_list.append(float(x))
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a number!!!")
```

If you need to ensure that `i` doesn't increment if the `ValueError` is handled, you may been to use a while loop, incrementing `i` explicitly.

```
n = 5
i = 0
n_list = []
while i < n:
    x = input('enter exponent n(q to quit) >')
    if i != 0 and x == 'q':
        return n_list 
    elif i == 0 and x == 'q':
        return ''
    try:
        n_list.append(float(x))
        i += 1
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a number!!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... when the exception of valueerror occurs is there a way where i can return back to the begging of the loop for the same iteratiom."*

Use a *while-loop* conditional to *n*, and decrement only when the input parses.

```py
n = 5
n_list = []
while n:
    s = input('enter exponent n(q to quit) >')
    if s == 'q': break
    try:
        n_list.append(float(s))
        n -= 1
    except ValueError:
        print(f"invalid entry '{s}'")
```

Here are some example outputs.

```
enter exponent n(q to quit) >1.2
enter exponent n(q to quit) >abc
invalid entry 'abc'
enter exponent n(q to quit) >3.4
enter exponent n(q to quit) >5.6
enter exponent n(q to quit) >7.8
enter exponent n(q to quit) >9
[1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8, 9.0]
```

```
enter exponent n(q to quit) >1.2
enter exponent n(q to quit) >3.4
enter exponent n(q to quit) >q
[1.2, 3.4]
```

On a final note, you mention the following.

> *"...input should accept any floating point values for n and terminate if ‘q’ is entered as the first value. If ‘q’ is entered as the second, third, fourth or fifth value, the program should produce a plot with only those values. ..."*

You can delegate the *return-value* with a method.

Here is an example.

```py
def f(n):
    n_list = []
    while n:
        s = input('enter exponent n(q to quit) >')
        if s == 'q':
            if not n_list: return None
            return n_list
        try:
            n_list.append(float(s))
            n -= 1
        except ValueError:
            print(f"invalid entry '{s}'")
    return n_list
```

Output

```
enter exponent n(q to quit) >q
None
```

```
enter exponent n(q to quit) >1.2
enter exponent n(q to quit) >3.4
enter exponent n(q to quit) >q
[1.2, 3.4]
```

Comment: return n_list or None

Answer (score 0):

```py
def main(n=0):
    n_list=[]
    for _ in range(n):
        value = None
        while value is None:
            x = input('Enter exponent n (q to quit) >')
            if x == 'q':
                return n_list if n_list else ''
            try:
                value = float(x)
            except:
                print(f'Error the value: >{x}< is not valid')
                continue
            n_list.append(value)
    return n_list

l = main(n=5)
print(l)
```